# how to prevent twice Google maps v 3.0 user permission alert in phone-Gap?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, userlocation

I'm using Google map API 3.0 in my site,i build my site with PhoneGap ,twice user permission alert appeared.
How to prevent these alerts ?

Comment: where you called the google map script. Share your code for better understanding

Comment: It could be you are trying to get the user's location before `deviceready` has fired causing the app to use the built in browser user location functionality instead of PhoneGap's. It might be that at some other stage you are also firing the user location functionality of PhoneGap (they have the same method signatures, PhoneGaps just kind of overrides the browser one, AFAIK). But without some code it's very hard to tell.